# Docker run: pass raw env variables

Tags: docker

I've been banging my head against a wall for a couple hours trying to figure this out.

My node.js code uses an environment variable `GAC` to authenticate with google cloud.

```
let { GAC } = process.env
const firestore = new Firestore({ keyFilename: GAC })
```

`GAC` is the path to the json file that contains secret keys, ids, etc.

On my local machine, `printenv` displays:

```
GAC="${HOME}/project-id.json"
```

And obviously the file itself is located where it should be.

Now I want to run a docker container, passing it the `GAC` variable and the json file, so that my code can run as normal.

```
$ docker run \
-e GAC=$GAC \
-v $GAC:$GAC \
-t image \
printenv
```

I want to pass the **unexpanded** `GAC` variable to docker. So `printenv` inside the container should show the exact same thing as `printenv` on my local machine.

`GAC="${HOME}/project-id.json"`

However the `$GAC` variable is expanded by the shell before the command is run. So `printenv` inside the container ends up looking like this

`GAC="C:\Users\eric\project-id.json"`

which is incorrect.

How do I do this properly? I want my code to retrieve the `GAC` env variable, no matter if its being run on my local machine or in a container.

Comment: Not pertinent to the question, but you're missing some quotes -- it should be `-e GAC="$GAC"` to prevent the value from being string-split and glob-expanded on the command line. Likewise, `-v "$GAC:$GAC"`. You'd have a bad time were your code run in a context with, say, `IFS=/` otherwise.

Comment: Speaking more directly to the question: If you run `set -x` before your `docker run` command, what does that shell log that it's invoking?

Comment: The Docker image has a known, fixed filesystem layout; why not just use fixed paths?  `docker run -v "$GAC:/gac" -e GAC=/gac`?

Comment: @Charles `set -x`  returns a ton of gibberish. @David Why not indeed.. haha thanks, I was busy over complicating things. I didn't consider the fact that I could simply change the file paths and the filename.

Comment: @EricGuan, yes, it's potentially a lot of content (especially if you're running this in a heavily customized interactive shell that builds a new prompt every time it's printed, so you're seeing all the code from that operation), but you only need to pick out the one line where it logs the invocation of `docker run` to simplify this question. And I assure you, that log wouldn't be gibberish to everyone here. :)